# Determine start of data's most recent uninterrupted 'streak' by date

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a dataset that looks something like:

```
asset_id,date_logged
1234,2018-02-01
1234,2018-02-02
1234,2018-02-03
1234,2018-02-04
1234,2018-02-05
1234,2018-02-06
1234,2018-02-07
1234,2018-02-08
1234,2018-02-09
1234,2018-02-10
9876,2018-02-01
9876,2018-02-02
9876,2018-02-03
9876,2018-02-07
9876,2018-02-08
9876,2018-02-09
9876,2018-02-10
```

For the purpose of this exercise, imagine today's date is 2018-02-10 (10 Feb 2018). For all the asset_ids in the table, I am trying to identify the start of the most recent unbroken streak for date_logged.

For asset_id = 1234, this would be 2018-02-01. The asset_id was logged all 10 days in an unbroken streak. For asset_id = 9876, this would be 2018-02-07. Because the asset_id was not logged on 2018-02-04, 2018-02-05, and 2018-02-06, the most recent unbroken streak starts on 2018-02-07.

So, my result set would hopefully look something like:

```
asset_id,Number_of_days_in_most_recent_logging_streak
1234,10
9876,4
```

Or, alternatively:

```
asset_id,Date_Begin_Most_Recent_Streak
1234,2018-02-01
9876,2018-02-07
```

I haven't been able to work out anything that gets me close -- my best effort so far is to get the number of days since the first log date and today, and the number of days the asset_id appears in the dataset, and compare these to identify situations where the streak is more recent than the first day they appear. For my real dataset this isn't particularly problematic, but it's an ugly solution and I would like to understand a better way of getting to the outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this. Break the query after each inline view in the WITH clause and SELECT * FROM the most recent inline view, to see what each step does.

```
with
  inputs ( asset_id, date_logged ) as (
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-06', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 1234, to_date('2018-02-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-08', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-09', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual union all
    select 9876, to_date('2018-02-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
  ),
  prep ( asset_id, date_logged, grp ) as (
    select asset_id, date_logged, 
           date_logged - row_number() 
                         over (partition by asset_id order by date_logged)
    from   inputs
  ),
  agg ( asset_id, date_logged, cnt ) as (
    select   asset_id, min(date_logged), count(*)
    from     prep
    group by asset_id, grp
  )
select   asset_id, max(date_logged) as date_start_recent_streak,
         max(cnt) keep (dense_rank last order by date_logged) as cnt
from     agg
group by asset_id
order by asset_id  -- If needed
;

  ASSET_ID DATE_START_RECENT_STREAK        CNT
---------- ------------------------ ----------
      1234 2018-02-01                       10
      9876 2018-02-07                        4
```

Comment: This I think is the solution, as it appears to accommodate multiple gaps in the date_logged activity, reporting the most recent begin date regardless of the number of gaps. Thank you!

Comment: Follow up: I was a little thrown by the way you are using row_number() to create grouping (or 'clumping'?), but it really seems to work!

Comment: @MidnightThoughtful - I only learned that trick, I didn't invent it. It is known variously as the "tabibitoan method" or "fixed differences method" - if you Google for either term, you will find plenty of hits, with explanation and many examples. If you look for "gaps and islands problems" (the class of problems to which yours belong), you will also see it mentioned often in those links. It is surprising how often this trick can be used.

Comment: "Gaps and islands" is exactly the concept I was trying to Google for originally, but I wasn't aware of the term so I was trying to look for "unbroken streaks" and not getting a lot of useful information. Thanks for adding the term to my vocabulary, that will make things easier in future! You should also check out @eifla001 's modified answer, as this achieves the same result in less code.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this,

```
with test (asset_id, date_logged) as
   (select 1234, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-09' from dual union all
   select 1234, date '2018-02-10' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-09' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-10' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-11' from dual union all
   select 9876, date '2018-02-12' from dual
 ) 
SELECT asset_id, MIN(date_logged), COUNT(1)
  FROM (SELECT asset_id, date_logged, 
               MAX(date_logged) OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id)+1 max_date_logged_plus_one,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY asset_id ORDER BY date_logged desc) rown
          FROM test
         ORDER BY asset_id, date_logged desc)
 WHERE max_date_logged_plus_one - date_logged = rown 
 GROUP BY asset_id;


  ASSET_ID MIN(DATE_LOGGED)   COUNT(1)
  ---------- ---------------- ----------
        1234 01-FEB-18                10
        9876 07-FEB-18                 6
```

if below data is commented, output is

```
select 9876, date '2018-02-10' from dual union all

  ASSET_ID MIN(DATE_LOGGED)   COUNT(1)
---------- ---------------- ----------
      1234 01-FEB-18                10
      9876 11-FEB-18                 2
```

Comment: This appears to have the same 'problem' as the code from @Littlefoot. If there is more than one gap in the date_logged streak, it reports the oldest instead of the newest. To see this, add records to the UNION ALL for each asset_id for 2018-02-11 and 2018-02-12. For asset_id 9876, comment out the record for 2018-02-10. Your code still shows 2018-02-07 as the beginning of the streak, rather than 2018-02-11. Edit: prematurely hit enter

Comment: That looks like it works! I'm not sure what the protocol is -- I already marked  mathguy's post as the accepted answer, but your query appears to be more succinct. Upvoting your post, many thanks for looking at this again.

Answer (score 0):

Would this make any sense?

```
SQL> with test (asset_id, date_logged) as
  2    (select 1234, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
  3     select 1234, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
  4     select 1234, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
  5     select 1234, date '2018-02-04' from dual union all
  6     select 1234, date '2018-02-05' from dual union all
  7     select 1234, date '2018-02-06' from dual union all
  8     select 1234, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
  9     select 1234, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
 10     select 1234, date '2018-02-09' from dual union all
 11     select 1234, date '2018-02-10' from dual union all
 12     select 9876, date '2018-02-01' from dual union all
 13     select 9876, date '2018-02-02' from dual union all
 14     select 9876, date '2018-02-03' from dual union all
 15     select 9876, date '2018-02-07' from dual union all
 16     select 9876, date '2018-02-08' from dual union all
 17     select 9876, date '2018-02-09' from dual union all
 18     select 9876, date '2018-02-10' from dual
 19    ),
 20  inter as
 21    -- difference between DATE_LOGGED and its previous DATE_LOGGED
 22    (select asset_id,
 23       date_logged,
 24       date_logged - lag(date_logged) over (partition by asset_id order by date_logged) diff
 25     from test
 26    )
 27  select i.asset_id, min(i.date_logged) date_logged
 28  from inter i
 29  where nvl(i.diff, 1) = (select max(i1.diff) from inter i1
 30                          where i1.asset_id = i.asset_id
 31                         )
 32  group by i.asset_id
 33  order by i.asset_id;

  ASSET_ID DATE_LOGGE
---------- ----------
      1234 2018-02-01
      9876 2018-02-07

SQL>
```

Comment: This is almost there -- if there is more than one gap in the data, it appears to get the start from the oldest gap, rather than the from the newest gap. But still, very much an education, thank you!